# Visual Studio 2010 element names for theming

Tags: visual-studio-2010, themes

I am trying to figure out what the element name for the tooltip is in Visual Studio 2010 so that I can change the style using the extension found [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378). Anyone know what that is? I am using the default theme which seems to have a white to light grey gradient on it. This is less than optimal since the text for the functions are also white.

[alt text http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/6195/vs2010tooltip.png](http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/6195/vs2010tooltip.png)

In a more general question (and perhaps better), is there anything that maps the names as they are found in the theme to where they are in the IDE.

After switching through some settings, I now believe it is not the IDE theme and is instead in the settings, but can't find which field it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adianbanks is correct go to **Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors**.  The field you posted looks like **Signature Help Tooltip Background**.  It has been overlooked on several of the dark background themes that I have tried. Also, make sure to change the **Item Background** color.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to `Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors`, you need to change the combo box at the top to `Editor Tooltip` to change this style. In my Visual Studio though, I can only change the font, not the colours,