# Visual Studio 2019 - Finding name of theme Element

Tags: visual-studio, ide, themes, visual-studio-2019

A previous question - [Visual Studio 2010 element names for theming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053448/visual-studio-2010-element-names-for-theming) - has partially answered this, but not what I'm asking, so please don't forward me there.

First, I'm looking for the name of the tooltip background used in the theme editor (Color theme editor for visual studio 2019.)

Secondly, is there a more efficient method of finding these element names? I built this theme mostly by replacing known colors and then for unknowns, screen-shotting, paste to GIMP, get the HEX code search the xml file for the color, find the name, then return to the theme editor with the name and change the color.

The background color to the tooltip as you can see in the following image (outlined in red) is white, making the info generally unreadable. In the menu dialog mentioned in the referenced question, only the foreground color can be changed. The theme editor does not seem to have a field strictly for the tooltip background, so it is likely pulling this background from another unrelated field as visual studio tends to do.

[image]

To add to the confusion, in the above image is from a .cs file; on a .cshtml file, the tooltip looks like this. Evidently there are multiple tooltips, as there is also no syntax highlighting in the following example.
[image]

I realize this isn't **strictly** a coding question, but I still believe this to be the most appropriate place to ask the question - If I'm wrong, mods, please direct me to the proper place.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [color documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/ux-guidelines/color-value-reference-for-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) made by microsoft (with screenshots). Maybe it could help you finding what you are looking for.